# How to update a certain field depending on the fetch cteTable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to replace the 1st and 2nd parameter in DATEADD function depending on the result of cteTable. Is this something possible? Do I need to create a parameter? Thank you in advance. Happy new year!

```
;with cteDP as(
SELECT CODE, MEASSUREMENT, DEFEXPIRYDATEDAYS,
CASE WHEN MEASSUREMENT = 0 THEN 'DAY'
    WHEN MEASSUREMENT = 1 THEN 'WEEK'
    WHEN MEASSUREMENT = 2 THEN 'MONTH'
    WHEN MEASSUREMENT = 3 THEN 'YEARS'
    ELSE 'SECOND' 
    END AS MEASUREMENTINWORD
FROM PW001C06 C06 WHERE CODE IN ('ADC','MMC')
)
select * from cteDP

UPDATE P05
SET     P05.EXPIRYDATE =  CASE  
                        WHEN P05.CODE = 'ADC' THEN DATEADD('cteDocProperties.MEASUREMENTINWORD', @2nd parameter, EXPIRYDATE) 
                       -- WHEN P05.CODE = 'MMC' THEN DATEADD(YEAR, 4, EXPIRYDATE) 
                       -- WHEN P05.CODE = 'LD00' THEN DATEADD(YEAR, 3, EXPIRYDATE) 
                        ELSE EXPIRYDATE
                    END 
FROM   PW001P05 P05
       INNER JOIN cteDP
         ON cteDP.CODE = P05.CODE
WHERE  P05.PIN = 1
       AND P05.CODE IN ('ADC','MMC')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly `JOIN` to the table expression:

```
UPDATE P05
SET     
    P05.EXPIRYDATE =  CASE  
                        WHEN P05.CODE = 'ADC' THEN 
                           CASE WHEN MEASUREMENTINWORD = 'SECOND' 
                              THEN DATEADD(SECOND, MEASSUREMENT, EXPIRYDATE) 
                           CASE WHEN MEASUREMENTINWORD = 'DAY' 
                              THEN DATEADD(DAY, MEASSUREMENT, EXPIRYDATE) 
                           CASE WHEN MEASUREMENTINWORD = 'MONTH' 
                              THEN DATEADD(MONTH, MEASSUREMENT, EXPIRYDATE) 
                           CASE WHEN MEASUREMENTINWORD = 'YEAR' 
                              THEN DATEADD(YEAR, MEASSUREMENT, EXPIRYDATE) 
                           ELSE EXPIRYDATE
                       END 
FROM   PW001P05 P05
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT 
      CODE
      , MEASSUREMENT
      , DEFEXPIRYDATEDAYS
      , CASE 
           WHEN MEASSUREMENT = 0 THEN 'DAY'
           WHEN MEASSUREMENT = 1 THEN 'WEEK'
           WHEN MEASSUREMENT = 2 THEN 'MONTH'
           WHEN MEASSUREMENT = 3 THEN 'YEARS'
           ELSE 'SECOND' 
        END AS MEASUREMENTINWORD
   FROM PW001C06 C06 WHERE CODE IN ('ADC','MMC')
) cteDP
   ON cteDP.CODE = P05.CODE
WHERE  P05.PIN = 1
       AND P05.CODE IN ('ADC','MMC')
```

Comment: I was thinking the same. Nested case statement will do the job. I have 20+ code that needs to update. DEFEXPIRYDATEDAYS field is also tell the quantity of years/days/months. So 3 conditions, 1 for code, 1 for day/month/year and 1 for quantity. Is there a way to normalize it? Thank you.

Comment: @ArvinJohnSalandanan What is the logic behind the rest of the codes? Is it any different compared to the one for `CODE = 'ADC'`?

Comment: Its the same as other codes. Just thinking out loud if this can be normalize or can be loop so the script can be much shorter.

Comment: @ArvinJohnSalandanan Your best option is a query like the above. A `WHILE` loop may be shorter but it will give you worse performance.